# What is the best way to store and retrieve datas after clicking the previous Button Browser

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to know what is the best way to store and retrieve datas **only** after clicking the back button Browser ?

In my case, you have a list of items (different for each categories I have on my website) that appends in angularJS with the ng-repeat directive, and you can filter these items by clicking on the checkbox inputs. Obviously, each checkbox has a specific value corresponding to a filter.

When the user click on an item, it redirects you to an article (such as a blog post).
May be the user doesn't like this blog post so he clicks on the back button of his browser to go back to the item list.

But for now, I don't store checkbox tags that have been checked before and the items filtered.
I try with localStorage and sessionStorage in JS but datas are too persistants with this method.
I could make a trick like retrieving the datas if the REFERER matches with a specific url pattern, but it seems to be too tricky..

So any of you has a better idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the state object for this purpose. This one is accessible via history.state and will change when a user navigates to somewhere. It will also be restored when using back button etc. It is can be seen as a storage object that is linked directly to the url.

Comment: In fact I've just seen it right now, but it's still too persistant, what I want is too only retrieve the datas if the user press the back button after clicking on an item knowing that I have different categories with different datas stored for each of these categories (datas containing the checkbox inputs checked and the items filtered)

Comment: Maybe you could use the state object? This one is accessible via history.state and will change when a user navigates to somewhere. It will also be restored when using back button etc. It is can be seen as a storage object that is linked directly to the url.

Comment: It seems to be a great idea, i've just looked the behavior of this method and looks good !

It works as my tricky idea mentioned in my first post so Thank you.
Make your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the good one !
Or just edit this one